# Convolution without known pdfs in terms of z

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, convolution

I have looked at many sites with almost enough information for this to make sense... just not quite there yet.
So I have this convolution formula (w instead of z and $dx$ instead of $dy$):
$$f(w) = 
\int_{-^\infty}^{\infty} f_x(x)f_y(w-x)dx
$$
X and Y are independent, uniform random variables distributed from (0,1) for X and (1,2) for Y

I have a few ideas...
$fx(X) = 1_{(0,1)}(x)$ and  $fy(Y) = 1_{(1,2)}(y)$
and
$f_y(Y) = f_{w-x}(w-x)$

What I am trying to get is the limits. That is, the values $w$ will take on in certain ranges. I am having trouble getting to the pdfs and the appropriate limits. For example: $f_w(w) = what?\;if\; w < somenumber? \;Note: it\;can \;be \lt,\; \gt,\;\le,\;\ge,\;, etc $

And thank you!

*****Edit (twice)
So where I am (currently) at is this:
$$f(w) = \int_{-^\infty}^{\infty} 1_{(a,b)}(x)f_(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx $$
$$1_{1,2}(y) = f_{(w-x)}(w-x) = \int_{1}^{2} f_{(w-x)}d(w-x)$$
So, I think I derive the $f(x)dx$, derive $f(y)dy$, (because easier than looking at $(w-x)$), go back and replace the $y=(w-x)$. Then I would have pdfs, I think. Does this appear to be the correct course of action? And thank you again!

**Derived and evaluated:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
 0, & { x < 0 } \\
1, & {0 \le x \le 1/2} \\
0, & {x>1/2}
\end{cases}$$

$$f(w-x) = \begin{cases}
0, & {(w-x) < 1}\\
3/2, & {(w-x) \ge 2}\\
0, & {(w-x) > 2}
\end{cases} $$

So, now I need to work out (from the above) $f_w(w)$.

**Final Answer:

$$f(w) = \begin{cases}
0, & if \;\; {w < 1/2}\\
1/2, & if\;\; {3/2 \le w \le 2}\\
3/2, &  if\;\; {2 \le w \le 5/2}\\
2, & if \;\;{w > 5/2}
\end{cases} $$

Could someone pretty please check my math?? Thank you!
*******@ Joey Doey One more question, from the convolution formula I should be able to get the pdf (also per a comment below) but I'm not sure what to plug in where. I will need to this to find the Expected and Variance of W.

I found this terribly useful and came up with similar answers. [Find PDF of $X-Y$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2044264/find-pdf-of-x-y)

My problem is this part...
"You find it from the joint support. $  0≤z+y≤1,0≤y≤1⟹−1≤z≤1$"

I can't seem to figure out how both of the z+y and y inequalities evaluated to the z inequality. Still working on the pdf of W :( :)

Comment: Why do'nt  you plug in the  formula and derive the pdf?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that $X$ is a random variable whereas $x$ is a particular value that it can take. So $f_X$ is a function and $f_X(x)$ a possible value. If $f_X(x)=1_{(0,1)}(x)$, then the following are all equivalent:
$$1_{(0,1)}(w-y)=1,$$
$$w-y\in (0,1),$$
$$0<w-y<1.$$
Also note the very important fact that
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty 1_{(a,b)}(x)f(x)\,dx = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx.$$
Hopefully this will get you started.